# kartoza/geoserver helm chart - Session issue with multiple pods

Tags: geoserver, clustering, geohelm

I'm using kartoza/geoserver image tag: 2.23.0 helm chart v0.3.3 to deploy to EKS cluster.

This is my values.yaml file:

```
image:
  registry: docker.io
  repository: kartoza/geoserver
  tag: "2.18.0"
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

geoserverDataDir: /efs_geo_data/geoserver/docker_geoserver4/data
geowebcacheCacheDir: /efs_geo_data/geoserver/docker_geoserver4/gwc

geoserverUser: *****
geoserverPassword: *****

enableJSONP: true

javaopts: "-DALLOW_ENV_PARAMETRIZATION=true"

stable_extensions: authkey-plugin, authkey-plugin, netcdf-out-plugin, netcdf-plugin, sldservice-plugin, sqlserver-plugin, importer-plugin, csw-plugin, monitor-plugin

proxy_url: "https://example.org/geoserver"

stable_plugin_url: "https://sonik.dl.sourceforge.net"

tomcat_extras: true

existing_datadir: true

xframe_options: true

# Use this if you have predefined secrets
existingSecret: |

extraPodEnv: |
  - name: INITIAL_MEMORY
    value: "7G"
  - name: MAXIMUM_MEMORY
    value: "7G"
  - name: STABLE_EXTENSIONS
    value: authkey-plugin, authkey-plugin, netcdf-out-plugin, netcdf-plugin, sldservice-plugin, sqlserver-plugin, importer-plugin, csw-plugin, monitor-plugin


resources:
  requests:
    memory: "7G"
    cpu: "1"
  limits:
    memory: "7G"
    cpu: "4"

service:
  ## GeoServer service type
  type: ClusterIP
  # clusterIP: ""
  # externalIPs: ""
  port: 80

  # nodePort:

  labels: |
  annotations: |

affinity: {}

tolerations: {}

ingress:
  enabled: false
  annotations: {}
  labels: {}
  host: geoserver.hostname
  tls:
    enabled: false
    ## Provide secret name if tls is enabled
    secretName: geoserver-tls

# probe can be overridden
probe: |

networkPolicy:
  ## Enable creation of NetworkPolicy resources. Only Ingress traffic is filtered for now.
  ##
  enabled: false

  ## The Policy model to apply. When set to false, only pods with the correct
  ## client label will have network access to the port PostgreSQL is listening
  ## on. When true, PostgreSQL will accept connections from any source
  ## (with the correct destination port).
  ##
  allowExternal: true
```

So when I install this helm chart, the UI works fine when only one pod is provisioned. But when multiple pods are provisioned, the browser returns a "Too many redirects" issue. So now, we manually update the HPA to provision only 1 replica each time we run helm upgrade.

I am making using alb ingress controller. This is ingress definition file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: geoserver
  namespace: gis-geoserver
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: lb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS":443}, {"HTTP":80}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: "arn:aws:acm:eu-central-1:**********:certificate/2889fd43-ca76-43b4-9198-19db635188d8"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: '443'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTP
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-interval-seconds: "15"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: "/geoserver"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: traffic-port
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-timeout-seconds: "5"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthy-threshold-count: "2"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/unhealthy-threshold-count: "2"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: 200,201,302
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: subnet-07f514bebf9fa5cb4, subnet-0d3c3f111c01cfc36
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-group-attributes: deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds=30
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: albintdev
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
      
spec:
 # ingressClassName: alb   # Ingress Class 
  rules:
    - host: example.org
      http:
        paths:           
          - path: /geoserver
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: geoserver-geoserver
                port: 
                  number: 80
```

**Edit 1**: I managed to fix the redirect issue by scaling down number of pods to 1 and editing the Web UI mode to "DO_NOT_REDIRECT" under global settings after logging in to the web UI.
Now I'm facing inconsistencies in login/logout to Web UI, inconsistencies while making config changes in the Web UI, etc. I'm guessing this is something to do with sessions not being sticky, requests hitting different pods. Any idea how to make sessions stick here or if the issue is something else, please let me know of that as well.

**Edit 2**:I managed to fix the login/logout and web ui config change inconsistency issues. I managed to enable sticky sessions on the AWS ALB target group level by adding this line in the ingress.yaml file mentioned above: **alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-group-attributes: stickiness.enabled=true,stickiness.lb_cookie.duration_seconds=60**
Even though this has managed to fix the visible web UI sticky sessions issue, we have still identified other issues and is still testing it comprehensively.

One such issue is: When layers are published via APIs, sometimes the layer is not visible on the web UI but visible the other times. So there's that inconsistency. Please advice.

Comment: where does `https://example.org/geoserver` point? But you probably shouldn't mix GUI access with a cluster of machines as it will get confused

Comment: @IanTurton I've added the ingress definition file with the question, the url points to the service of the geoserver. This is the reference to the helm chart repo: https://github.com/kartoza/charts/tree/develop/charts/geoserver

Comment: Hi @IanTurton I've updated the question with things I've tried and tested. Please go through it and share your thoughts.